# url rewrite .htaccess extension to permalink

Tags: permalinks, htaccess

I have a custom page and template, that I'm passing a query-string to. It has a wordpress permalink like so

/mypage/

I want to be able to add another rule so that the permalink receives a slug

/mypage/this-slug

is rewrote to

/mypage/?myslug=this-slug

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work for you-

```
function wpse28906_rewrites_init(){
    add_rewrite_rule(
        'mypage/([^/]+)/?$',
        'index.php?pagename=mypage&myslug=$matches[1]',
        'top' );
}
add_action( 'init', 'wpse28906_rewrites_init' );

function wpse28906_query_vars( $query_vars ){
    $query_vars[] = 'myslug';
    return $query_vars;
}
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'wpse28906_query_vars' );
```

You can then use `get_query_var( 'myslug' )` in your template to get your slug value. Don't forget to flush your rewrite rules after adding this by visiting the permalinks settings page.

Comment: how do i flush the rewrite rules? I visited the page and hit save. I cant access get_query_var( 'myslug' ).

Comment: @madphp - just visiting the permalinks settings page flushes them. `echo get_query_var( 'myslug' )` should echo the value of `myslug` if it's set. if you visit `/mypage/anything/` and don't get a 404 or redirected, then the rewrite rule is working.

Comment: do I need to use add_rewrite_tag somewhere? http://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_tag . I dont get a 404, by going to /mypage/anything/ but i cant access the myslug query_var.

Comment: Im using WordPress 3.0.4

Comment: I can access query variable like this. $wp->query_vars['myslug']; Is that acceptable?

Comment: @madphp - why are you using an old version? you should definitely update for reasons of security. I can't test on that version, but this works as-is on 3.2.1. try disabling plugins and using the default theme to see if something else is interfering.

Comment: @madphp - oops, missed your last comment. yes, it's safe, there must be something else interfering somewhere though that's causing get_query_var to not work.

Comment: using a buddypress/wordpress site. I dont think its straight forward to upgrade, though I should look into that again for sure.